# create an Excel Named Range that goes until a condition is met

Tags: excel, named-ranges

I would like to create several Named Ranges in Excel that collect values in each column until the cell in a different row is blank.  So for instance I have a Named Range called Weeks and the range is from DB3 to FA3.  I would to dynamically get all the values until a blank is found in row 4.  So if a blank is found at EO4, my Weeks range would pull in values from DB3 to EO3.  Does that make sense?  I am using Excel 2010 by the way.
Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define the name as `=OFFSET($DB$3,0,0,1,COUNTA($DB$3:$FA$3))`

This is using the info from [ozgrid](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/DynamicRanges.htm)

Comment: That last part COUNTA($DB$3:$FA$3)) just needs to be switched to COUNTA($DB$4:$FA$4)) or whichever row I am checking for empty data and it works perfect!  Thank you!